# Quickfix/C++ - Ordering fields

Tags: quickfix

I'm currently trying to speak in FIX using Quickfix/C++ to a Financial Market.
This market rejects my message (a RegistrationInstruction, msgtype=o), telling me that a field is not in the correct place.

The problem is that the specified tag (#29 LastCapacity) is sent by quickfix between field SecurityIDSource #22 and SecurityID #48 and the market tell me that the Instrument "component" should be sent as defined by the specifications which is:

```
Start <instrument>
55 Symbol
48 SecurityID
22 SecurityIDSource
167SecurityType
end <Instrument>
```

Then Tag #29 Should not appear inside this component.

Do you have any idea how may I tell quickfix to not send #29 between #22 and #48 ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Is the field part of a repeating group? The order is not relevant, *except* if the field appears in a repeating group. At the very least, include a code fragment that constructs the message in your question please.

Comment: In fact, the field is not part of a repeating group. But the server to which I sent the message complains that this field is inside a "block" that screw up its block reading process :-( ... I  know that field order is not relevant in this case, but unfortunetly, I should just do what my counterparty tell me to do. I've put this field inside a repeating group just to send it in another place. Now, this field is set only in the last group element and then, is at the end of the message.

Comment: Well then your counterparty is not FIX compliant... a pain for sure. It would at least help for people around here on the quickfix tag to include a code fragment that shows how you construct the message.

Comment: Also, field 29 is not part of at least the 4.4 version of [Registration Instructions](http://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.4/msgType_o_111.html). No idea why you should send that. The field [LastCapacity](http://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.4/tagNum_29.html) shouldn't appear in that instruction. Are you sure it is this instruction that is being rejected? Fields 22 and 48 also do not appear in that message...

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the problem, I used an existing repeating group inside the message and add the Tag #29 inside it, and initialize it only on the last element of the inserted group elements (I could not copy-paste nor send code outside, sorry).

Comment: I trimmed the part that was not an answer (answering section is reserved just for that).

Comment: What nested group it happened to be ? Can you please share that ?